# Axios does not send cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios, vite

I use React/vite for frontend and Express for backend, i created a google authentication method on app, it work local but on hosting (render.com) axios dosn't send cookies

Express cors

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: [
        `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}`,
        "*"
    ],
    credentials: true
}));
```

axios request

```
const getUser = async () => {
        try {
            const response: any = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/api/user/login/success`,
                {withCredentials: true})
            const json = await response.data
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json.token))
            dispatch({
                type: "LOGIN", payload: {
                    username: json.user.username,
                    balance: json.user.balance,
                    photo: json.user.photo,
                    email: json.user.email
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

local:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/login/success", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"110\", \"Not A(Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"110\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "cookie": "session=eyJwYXNzcG9ydCI6eyJ1c2VyIjoiNjNmNjYwNzFhOWZhZGE4NDYzNGEzMzM2In19; session.sig=e9nhRQsEKc9L6NLues62liSkGVw",
    "Referer": "http://localhost:4173/",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET"
});
```

same request on hosting:

```
fetch("https://onlina-game-backend-dev.onrender.com/api/user/login/success", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"110\", \"Not A(Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"110\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "Referer": "https://onlina-game-client-dev.onrender.com/",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET"
});
```

I think problem may be in vite

Comment: Paste your backend cors header code.

Comment: Do you add `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);`

Comment: My backend cors

app.use(cors({
    origin: [
        `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}`,
        "*"
    ],
    credentials: true
}));

Comment: inspect request headers in devtools network panel.

Comment: i did it, request have no cookies